# how to do something like this in sqlalchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy

Assuming that:

```
class Users(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String)
```

how can i do this in sqlalchemy:

```
select id,username,0 as deleted from users
```

which `deleted` is not in `users`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal)

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import literal
db.session.query(User.id, User.username, literal(0).label('deleted'))
```